# freeDiameter - Event-Timestamp

Tags: c, free-diameter

I just had one question about "Event-Timestamp" AVP.

I know that i should put the epoch time in there, but i mainly concerned about its format, it is what i found in RFC so far:

```
8.21.  Event-Timestamp AVP

 The Event-Timestamp (AVP Code 55) is of type Time, and MAY be
 included in an Accounting-Request and Accounting-Answer messages to
 record the time that the reported event occurred, in seconds since
 January 1, 1900 00:00 UTC.


Time
  The Time format is derived from the OctetString AVP Base Format.
  The string MUST contain four octets, in the same format as the
  first four bytes are in the NTP timestamp format.  The NTP
  Timestamp format is defined in chapter 3 of [SNTP].

  This represents the number of seconds since 0h on 1 January 1900
  with respect to the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

  On 6h 28m 16s UTC, 7 February 2036 the time value will overflow.
  SNTP [SNTP] describes a procedure to extend the time to 2104.
  This procedure MUST be supported by all DIAMETER nodes.
```

So, the question is should i first get the system current time (in epoch format) and then convert it to string and pass it to Event-Timestamp directly ?

But the standard says: "`The string MUST contain four octets`".

I dont know how to achieve this ... could you please elaborate on this ?

Comment: A reference to the document you are following would be nice to facilitate the analisys of your problem.  The referenced document is [RFC-3588 Diameter based protocol]:<https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3588#section-8.21>

Comment: Are you asking questions and answering yourself online?+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem here is that you have a reference in the RFC you are reading that links you to the NTP rfc for a definition of the NTP timestamp.

The 4 first bytes of the NTP timestamp show you the integer part (in seconds) from the epoch to the time the timestamp was acquired.

The `time(2)` function gives you a `time_t` value (some architectures have a 64bit `time_t`, and some have 32, you have to be able to know which one you have) **BUT WITH A DIFFERENT EPOCH**.  This is what you are doing bad.  The epoch in NTP is 00:00h 1st/jan/**1900** and in UNIX time is 00:00h 1st/jan/**1970**, so you have to correct for that difference in seconds to compensate for those 70 years difference.

To convert a unix `time()` time to NTP seconds, you have to add the constant `2208988800U` (be careful, as this constant has to be unsigned in 32bit architectures, as it has the msb on, to not being interpreted as a negative value) to the `time_t` value, or make your calculations in 64bit mode.

So, finally, your code should be:

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
time_t t2 = t + 2208988800UL;

bytes[0] = (t2 >> 24) & 0xFF;
bytes[1] = (t2 >> 16) & 0xFF;
bytes[2] = (t2 >> 8) & 0xFF;
bytes[3] = t2 & 0xFF;
```

(as both timestamps are referred to UTC, no local conversions are needed)

Comment: Thanks for reply Luis :) I liked the part you explained about difference between unix and ntp definition on epoch time. should noticed that before :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the RFC should be re-strictly followed :)
Converting the epoch time to bytes (length = 4) did the trick.

Update:
It didnt really worked out :/

I mean now, the message is ok from AVP format point of view .. however the time is not correct ..

I used below code to create the epoch time and convert to byte array:

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
tm tmp;
tmp.tm_isdst = -1;
tmp = *localtime( &t );
time_t t2 = mktime( &tmp );

bytes[0] = (t2 >> 24) & 0xFF;
bytes[1] = (t2 >> 16) & 0xFF;
bytes[2] = (t2 >> 8) & 0xFF;
bytes[3] = t2 & 0xFF;
```

But as you can see in below screen shot , the time is actually not correct:

[image]

Could you please tell me what i did wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: I must add that when i debug "t2" variable, the value is just correct, i guess there is something wrong when i convert to byte array

Comment: Have you actually read the manual page for the `time(2)` function?  Did you follow the reference to the NTP timestamp format described in the NTP RFC?  Have you taken into account the difference in time between 1/1/1900 and 1/1/1970 ????  You did many things bad, see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

"fd_dictfct_Time_encode" function is the answer :)

Comment: where did that `fd_dictfct_Time_encode` function come?  Is it on any standard defined?